# Multiple curl in parallel with limitations

Tags: bash, unix, curl, parallel-processing

I have a json file, with entries containing urls (among other things), which i retrieve using curl.
I'd like to be able to run the loop several times at once to go faster, but also to have a limitation of the number of parallel curls, to avoid being kicked out by the distant server.
For now, my code is like

```
  jq -r '.entries[] | select(.enabled != false) | .id,.unitUrl' $fileIndexFeed | \
  while read unitId; do
    read -r unitUrl
    if ! in_array tabAnnoncesExistantesIds $unitId; then
      fullUnitUrl="$unitUrlBase$unitUrl"
      unitFile="$unitFileBase$unitId.json"
      if [ ! -f $unitFile ]; then
        curl -H "Authorization:$authMethod $encodedHeader" -X GET $fullUnitUrl -o $unitFile
      fi
    fi
   done
```

If i use a simple & at the end of my curl, it will run lots of concurrent requests, and i could be kicked.
So, the question would be (i suppose) : how to know that a curl runned with an & has finished its job ? If i'm able to detect that, then i guess that i can test, increment and decrement a variable telling the number of running curls.

Thanks

Comment: will checking for ps -ef|grep -i curl |wc -l  before running the curl command help? you can keep a check to sleep if the number of curl processes running in the system has reached your defined limit. once the num of processes drops, you can run the next curl. Is this what is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **GNU Parallel** to control the number of parallel jobs. Either write your `curl` commands to a file so you can look at them and check them:

`commands.txt`

```
curl "something" "somehow" "toSomewhere"
curl "somethingelse" "someotherway" "toSomewhereElse"
```

Then, if you want no more than 8 jobs running at a time, run:

```
parallel -j 8 --eta -a commands.txt
```

Or you can just write the commands to **GNU Parallel**'s `stdin`:

```
jq ... | while read ...; do
    printf "curl ..." 
done | parallel -j 8
```

Comment: This really pointed me in the right direction : i split my process in several parts to make it more efficient, since the in_array function in bash was painfully slow.
I got the full list of urls, cleaned it in php, generated a text file, and only then used a bash to parallel it. And i t was much simpler, since all the pre-processing was done outside.

Thanks a lot anyway,you saved me hours.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Bash function:

```
doit() {
  unitId="$1"
  unitUrl="$2"
  if ! in_array tabAnnoncesExistantesIds $unitId; then
    fullUnitUrl="$unitUrlBase$unitUrl"
    unitFile="$unitFileBase$unitId.json"
    if [ ! -f $unitFile ]; then
      curl -H "Authorization:$authMethod $encodedHeader" -X GET $fullUnitUrl -o $unitFile
    fi
  fi
}

jq -r '.entries[] | select(.enabled != false) | .id,.unitUrl' $fileIndexFeed |
  env_parallel -N2 doit
```

`env_parallel` will import the environment, so all shell variables are available.